# Why i cant set procent values in boostrap

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I want to make a bar with (thin bar) but as I am using bootstrap, I can't fully control sizes;

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid mx-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="square rounded-pill"></div>
      <div class="square rounded-pill"></div>
      <div class="square rounded-pill"></div>
      <div class="square rounded-pill"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  setup() {},
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.container-fluid {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center !important;
}

.square {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 3vh;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

I want to set the `.container-fluid` height to `50%` but I cant, I want to set .square width and height in % and I can't, and above all the items dont want to align center, in .row justifycontent works, but align items: center don`t?
How can I describe the sizes in % and align items center?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to set the `width` and `height` of any Bootstrap element in viewport-based units. These are `vh`, `vw`, `vmin` and `vmax`. Percentages doesn't work the way you want to use them. For example, a value of `1vh` is equal to `1%` of the viewport height. See the snippet below.

For the `align-items` part, what are you trying to achieve? What do you want to align vertically?

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">Lorem ipsum</div>
</body>

</html>
```